# Is it possible to implement authentication for showing Barcode in Apple wallet?

Tags: ios, passbook, wallet

The app which I have downloads the pass adds to Apple wallet.
I want to secure the barcode with an authentication, something like a pin verification or even TouchID.

Till the authentication is successful, user should not see the barcode aligned to the Pass in Apple wallet.

Couldn't find any lead in any forums.

Is this even possible?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is nothing like this available per Apple's documentation.  I agree that, for particular use-cases, there should be the option for such an implementation.

Comment: Thank you @Dan for clarifying this.